# How to use BS4 to detect no table data on page

Tags: selenium, pandas, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am having difficulty parsing this HTML table using BS4. Sometimes the page doesn't have payment data and will say "There is no pending manifest payment". Other times, the page will list out all the pending payments due. I'd like to have this data output into an array.

```
def find_payment(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find('table', cellspacing="0", cellpadding="2", border="0")
    table_body = table.find('tbody')
    rows = table.body.find_all('tr')
    payment_data = []
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        account_data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
    return payment_data
```

[image]

[image]

For the most part, solved. I did something like this:

```
def find_payment(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    if soup.find(text="There is no pending manifest payment") is not None:
        payment_data.append([0, ID[i]])
    else:
        amount = soup.find('td', {'class': 'bodytext'}, width="35%")
        payment_data.append([amount.text, ID[i]])
    return payment_data
```

Comment: Is possible use [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) and then use `pandas`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just soup lookup for the "td" with class either **success** or **body10**?

```
 def find_payments(html):    
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        if soup.find("td", {"class":"success"}):
            payments = "There is no pending manifest payment"
        else:
            payments = [pmnt.text for pmnt in soup.findAll("td", {"class":"body10"})]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to be a bit *defensive* (sort of [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl) style) and search for the "There is no pending manifest payment" element beforehand:

```
if soup.find(text="There is no pending manifest payment") is not None:
    print("No payment data")
```

Comment: Thanks for the nifty suggestion.